# On Minecraft Servers, are you able to see an item's player history?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

For example are you able to see the history of every player that handled a specific item? Either through console or through a plugin?

If so, do items that are convertible from ingot to block, such as Blocks of Iron, become new objects on the server or are you able to trace their history?

I am doing this to avoid duping on my server.

Comment: There is no way to prevent duping on a server.
You report it as a bug to either Mojang, explain to the players that have discovered/abused the dupe, that using said exploit would get them banned from the server without the right to appeal, depending on your server rules and/or policies.

Answer (score 1):

### Not in vanilla.

While yes logs are kept of some things in vanilla, they are not so detailed as to allow you to track an items complete history. There are some plugins like CoreProtect which do have extensive logging features. It may also be possible with datapacks, however I do not know of any which do this. Either way these are not the best way to prevent duping. The best way to prevent duping is to not have it at all by using anti dupe plugins.